# Maximal Solution Theorem Interpretation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have the theorem for the maximal solution of a differential equation, namely:

Let $x: [t_0, T) \to \mathbb R$ be the maximal solution.  Then one of the following holds:

1) $T = \infty $

2) $T \lt \infty$ and $x=\lim_{t \to T} x(t)$ D.N.E

3) $T \lt \infty$ and $x=\lim_{t \to T}$ exists but $(T,x)$ not in the domain

I know and understand examples from the first two cases, but I can't seem to think of an example of the third case, and I was wondering if anyone had an example of that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the equation 
$$y'=-\dfrac{1}{2\,y},\quad y(0)=1.
$$
The maximal solution is $y(t)=\sqrt{1-t}$ on $[0,1)$. We have $\lim_{t\to1^-}y(t)=0$ and $(1,0)$ is not in the domain of definition of the equation.