# Question about boundaries in ODE, with extension of solutions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f:[0,+\infty) \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, continuous. I need some help to show that:

> If $\phi:[0,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ is continuous and $g(t)$ is a non-continuable solution of $g'=f(t,g)$, definided on $[0,w)$ where $|g(t)| \leq \phi(t), t\in [a,w)$, then $w = +\infty$.

Comment: What do you know about the characterization of maximal solutions? Essentially, if the solution can not leave the domain in vertical direction, then it has to leave it in horizontal direction, that is, continue to the maximal time present in the domain.

Comment: @LutzLehmann There is some text where I can see those results about the characterization? And yes, it was a typo, you're right about $g'(t)$.

Comment: @Rem a solution that cannot be extended. So, if I suppose that $w < \infty$, then as $\phi$ is continuous, in a finite interval it's maximum value is finite; so, it contradicts the theorem that Lutz remembers above.

Comment: @big_GolfUniformIndia Thank you, I found after it was similar to maximal solution. Is there any difference between the two terms?

Comment: Local links to the [theorem of the maximal solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3719718/maximal-solution) or in a [more simple, one-sided formulation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666461/maximal-solution-theorem)

Comment: That depends on what the exact definition of the not so usual term "non-continuable solution" is. It should be the same, but from the feeling of the words there could be a demand of a definitive end-point from where continuation is impossible.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks for the references!